# Did Hitler survive until 1962?

Tags: history, adolf-hitler

I noticed this book, "Grey Wolf: The Escape Of Adolf Hitler", mentioned (without real criticism) in a major Icelandic newspaper. According to the article, the book claims Hitler did not kill himself, and the authors claim to have proof that he lived in Argentina until he died from natural causes in 1962.

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402781393) describes the book thus:

> Did Hitler (code name Grey Wolf) really die in 1945? The evidence says no. Heres the gripping story of what might have happened... When Truman asked Stalin in 1945 whether Hitler was dead, Stalin replied bluntly, No. As late as 1952, Eisenhower declared: We have been unable to unearth one bit of tangible evidence of Hitler's death. What really happened? Simon Dunstan and Gerrard Williams have compiled extensive evidence, some recently declassified, that Hitler actually fled Berlin and took refuge in a remote Nazi enclave in Argentina. The recent discovery that the famous Hitler's skull in Moscow is female, as well as newly uncovered documents, provide powerful proof for their case. Dunstan and Williams cite people, places and dates in over 500 detailed notes that identify the plan's escape route, vehicles, aircraft, U-boats and hideouts. Among the details: the CIA's possible involvement and Hitler's life in Patagonia, including his two daughters.

Has anyone here read the book?

Is there any proof of these claims?

Is there any proof of his death in 1945?

Comment: +1 This question just profoundly unsettled me. Thank you for contesting supposed truth!

Comment: Because its an anecdote I cant use this as an answer but one of the reviews says "No Hard Credible Documentation or Actual Evidence"...  I Think that pretty much sums it up.  There have been lots of conspiracy stories about Hitler living in the Andes until the 80's or 90' I swear every few months the National Enquirer or its ilk would run a story about how he had been found/killed/arrested...

Comment: What could the CIA possibly have gained by helping Hitler escape, besides the possibility of an enormous, treasonous scandal?

Answer (score 19):

The death of Hitler is extensively documented, with copious source material summarized in the Wikipedia article on the [Death of Adolf Hitler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Adolf_Hitler#cite_note-14).

The authors' claim of being "unable to unearth one bit of tangible evidence of Hitler's death" in light of that bibliography is utter sensationalist bunk.

A cursory look at the [book reviews on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402781393) confirms numerous errors, the fabrication of facts, and a general lack of supporting evidence for the authors' claims.

All of this could have been gleaned from a basic, third-grade book report, internet search.

Comment: The first reviewer cites The Daily Mail (and a person contacted by The Daily Mail). Should we trust a review that cites them?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm agreed

Comment: This is a good answer – however, unfortunately I have to remove the quote since it’s extensive and doesn’t fall under fair use. Could you maybe include just the salient portions needed to underscore your answer? In its current form it’s a copyright violation.

Comment: I beefed up the sentence that offers a summary of Amazon reviews. Thank you for the edits @KonradRudolph.

Comment: "We couldn't find any evidence that..." is a sentence that always should be looked at askance because it sounds like an attempt to avoid the counter question "Did you actually look for any?"

Comment: I looked at the Amazon reviews: the reviews which give the book "5 stars" find it believable; nearly half of the book's reviews are "5 star", nearly half of the rest are "4 star". There is historical documentation (presumably witness' narratives) cited in the Wikipedia article, but are you referring to any specific "tangible evidence" in your answer?

Comment: Can't see any concrete example of him being dead that day. No body identification, no DNA test. All you can find in this wiki is a story and not documentation.

Answer (score 10):

According to declassified FBI documents, there was information from an informant claiming Adolf Hitler arrived in Argentina via submarine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Did Adolf Hitler live till 1962?

I can't immediately say from these documents, there's a lot to work through and the quality is fairly poor, but the FBI certainly found it plausible that Adolf Hitler was still alive after the fall of Berlin.

[FBI Vault Hitler 1](http://vault.fbi.gov/adolf-hitler/adolf-hitler-part-01-of-04/at_download/file)

[FBI Vault Hitler 2](http://vault.fbi.gov/adolf-hitler/adolf-hitler-part-02-of-04/at_download/file)

[FBI Vault Hitler 3](http://vault.fbi.gov/adolf-hitler/adolf-hitler-part-03-of-04/at_download/file)

[FBI Vault Hitler 4](http://vault.fbi.gov/adolf-hitler/adolf-hitler-part-04-of-04/at_download/file)

Looking at Wikipedia:

> Different versions of Hitler's fate were presented by the Soviet Union
>   according to its political desires. In the years immediately following
>   1945, the Soviets maintained Hitler was not dead, but had fled and was
>   being shielded by the former western allies.[51] This worked for a
>   time to create doubt among western authorities. The chief of the U.S.
>   trial counsel at Nuremberg, Thomas J. Dodd, said: "No one can say he
>   is dead." When President Harry S. Truman asked Stalin at the Potsdam
>   Conference in August 1945 whether or not Hitler was dead, Stalin
>   replied bluntly, "No". But by 11 May 1945, the Soviets had already
>   confirmed through Hitler's dentist, Hugo Blaschke, and his dental
>   technician that the dental remains found were Hitler's and
>   Braun's.[52] In November 1945, Dick White, then head of
>   counter-intelligence in the British sector of Berlin (and later head
>   of MI5 and MI6 in succession), had their agent Hugh Trevor-Roper
>   investigate the matter to counter the Soviet claims. His findings were
>   written in a report and published in book form in 1947.[53]
>
> In May 1946, SMERSH agents recovered from the crater where Hitler was
>   buried two burned skull fragments with gunshot damage. These remains
>   were apparently forgotten in the Russian State Archives until 1993,
>   when they were re-found.[54] In 2009 DNA and forensic tests were
>   performed on the skull fragment, which Soviet officials had long
>   believed to be Hitler's. According to the American researchers, the
>   tests revealed that the skull was actually that of a woman less than
>   40 years old. The jaw fragments which had been recovered in May 1945
>   were not tested.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ6P6.png)

Source: [Wikipedia on the Death of Adolf Hitler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Adolf_Hitler)

[Michael Mussmanno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Musmanno) wrote in his book `Ten Days to Die` that

> Russia must accept much of the blame that Hitler did not die in May
>   1945.

[James F. Byrnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_F._Byrnes) wrote in his book `Speaking Frankly`,

> While in Potsdam at the conference of the Big Four, Stalin left his
>   chair, came over and clicked his liquor glass with mine in a very
>   friendly manner.  I asked what was his theory about the death of Adolf
>   Hitler and he replied - Hitler is not dead.  He escaped either to
>   Spain or Argentina.

Comment: This is a great find.  However, this is is pure speculation: "*If they had concrete evidence that Hitler was dead, they would have dismissed the informant, instead they kept on gathering intel.*"  It was September, 1945 when you'd really, really, **REALLY** want to double check that Hitler is dead and not going to rally German partisans.  Even the rumor of Hitler being alive could do that.  I can excuse the FBI for wanting to check into any credible tip on escaped Nazi high command.

Comment: What did they (the US) have at that point? Russians telling them he's dead, Stalin saying he's alive, they had no body at the time and out of the blue comes a random informant telling them he knows where Hitler is ... 
So the US was sitting with conflicting information and no hard evidence to prove or disprove it ... maybe they simply didn't know.
Would be nice to see declassified Russian intel.